# To prove: For $p$ prime, $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}*$ and $ord(\zeta) = p$, $(1-\zeta)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$

Tags: roots-of-unity, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to solve the following:

Let $p$ be a prime number and $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}^* $ such that $ord(\zeta) = p$.
Show that $(1-\zeta)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ and that there is a unit $\epsilon \in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ such that
$$
p \ = \ \epsilon (1-\zeta)^{p-1}
$$

---

**My own thoughts**

Every $x \in (1-\zeta)$ can be written as $x'(1-\zeta)$ for some $x' \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. This allows me to describe its elements (in a ugly way), since 
$x' = a_0 +a_1 \zeta + \cdots + a_{p-2}\zeta^{p-2}$ 
for some 
$a_0, \cdots , a_n \in \mathbb{Z} $.
Rewriting gives us:
$$
x \quad = \quad (1-\zeta)(a_0+a_1\zeta + \cdots + a_{p-2}\zeta^{p-2})
$$
Which is
$$
(a_0 + \cdots + a_{p-2}\zeta^{p-2}) \ - \ (a_0\zeta+ \cdots + a_{p-3}\zeta^{p-2})
\ + \ a_{p-2}(1+\zeta + \cdots + \zeta^{p-2})
$$
So
$$
x \quad = \quad (a_0 + a_{p-2}) \ + \ (a_0-a_1+a_{p-2})\zeta \ + \ (a_1-a_2+a_{p-2})\zeta^2 \ + \  \cdots \ + \
(a_{p-3}-a_{p-2}+a_{p-2}) \zeta^{p-2}
$$
$x$ has a striking property: the sum of its coefficients is $a_n + (p-2)a_{p-2}$. I don't think that it entirely describes the ideal though.  I have to show that $a,b \notin (1-\zeta) \Rightarrow ab \notin (1- \zeta)$ but I don't see how I could do that.

---

Now I tell you what I tried to find an $\epsilon$ as described above. I expanded:
$$
(1-\zeta)^{p-1} 
\quad = \quad 
\sum_{0 \leq k \leq p-1}\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-1-k)!}(-\zeta)^k
\quad = \quad 
\sum_{0 \leq k \leq p-1}\left( \frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-1-k)!}-1 \right) (-\zeta)^k
$$
The last step is true by the fact that we can subtract $1+\zeta+ \zeta^2+\cdots + \zeta^{p-1}$ since this sum equals zero. In that way $1$ and $\zeta^{p-2}$ vanish, but I still don't see what kind of $\epsilon$ I could choose.

---

Here is what I tried to show that the statement given in the answer is true. 
I looked at the product: 
$\prod_{1 \leq k \leq p-1} (1- \zeta^k)$ If we take an automorphic map $\sigma$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$, it has to be described by $\sigma \ : \ \zeta \mapsto \zeta^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ggd(n,p) = 1$.By symmetry the given product has to be fixed, so it has to belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. Still busy...

Comment: You can avoid a lot of those messy computations. Do you already know that $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$? And do you know terms like the norm of an element/ideal and prime factorization in Dedekind domains?

Answer (score 1):

I try to leave the details:

Look at the quotient $\mathbb Z[\zeta]/(1-\zeta)$. As an abelian group it is generated by the classes of $1$ and the powers of $\zeta$. Since those classes coincide in the quotient, it is a cyclic group, generated by $1$. Since we have $p = \prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(1-\zeta^k)$ (left to the reader), we see $p \cdot 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb Z[\zeta]/(1-\zeta)$, in particular we deduce $\mathbb Z[\zeta]/(1-\zeta) \cong \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, hence the first assertion.

For the second assertion you should note that $(1-\zeta^k)$ ($1 \leq k \leq p-1$) and $(1-\zeta)$ are the same elements up to a unit. Then have another look at the above product.